# JSONObject create Json object issue

Tags: java, json

I trying to create the code which generates the JSON data which should look like this

```
{
  "Main": [
    {
      "prim": "Hello ",
      "secon": [
        {
          "ads": "A Message"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The code I am trying with is generating like below

```
{
  "Main": [
    {
      "prim": "Hello"
    },
    {
      "secon": [
        {
          "ads": "A Message"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Code:

```
JSONObject prim = new JSONObject();
prim.put("prim", Hello");

JSONObject ads = new JSONObject();
ads.put("ads", "A Message");

JSONArray seconArray = new JSONArray();
seconArray.put(ads);

JSONObject secon = new JSONObject();
secon.put("secon", seconArray);

JSONArray Main = new JSONArray();
Main.put(prim);
Main.put(secon);

JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();
jsonObj.put("Main", Main);

JSONArray topJson = new JSONArray();
topJson.put(jsonObj);
System.out.println(topJson.get(0).toString());
```

How to remove the unnecessary brackets and create the intended Json data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of:

```
 secon.put("secon", seconArray);
```

Try:

```
 prim.put("secon", seconArray);
```

And remove:

```
 Main.put(secon);
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I got where I was missing